# Power BI Auth2.0 integration with Autodesk BIM360/Forge

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, autodesk-forge

I am trying to make a custom power BI data connector to connect  Autodesk BIM360/Forge.
I have setup auth2.0 authentication as per the power BI github connect sample.The program runs fine in the debug environment in visual studio. But when running the same thing from inside power bi it freezes at authorization step.

Power BI Desktop Freezing in this page-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imX1o.png)

Visual Studio showing authentication generated-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIhIn.png)

Connector-https://mnc5d-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/sourav_ganguli/ETg4BHsRRMxGgPvnh5-z4l0BzDim1LBmz91vsSeaWDsysA?e=Oaak4j

Code-

```
 '''
    // This file contains your Data Connector logic
section PQExtension1;

client_id="VsuX1PRxOl0GQw4O52FNF9DsBgYHqPzN";
client_secret ="O0HHUVoxQFiom6XO";
Scope="data:read";
redirect_uri ="http://localhost:9000";
AuthorizeUrl="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?";
TokenUri="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken";

windowHeight=720;
windowWidth=720;





[DataSource.Kind="PQExtension1", Publish="PQExtension1.Publish"]
shared PQExtension1.Contents = (url as text) =>
    let
        source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url))
    in
        source;


// Data Source Kind description
PQExtension1 = [
    Authentication = [
        OAuth = [
            StartLogin = StartLogin,
            FinishLogin = FinishLogin
            ]
       // Implicit = []
    ],
    Label = Extension.LoadString("DataSourceLabel")
];

// Data Source UI publishing description
PQExtension1.Publish = [
    Beta = true,
    Category = "Other",
    ButtonText = { Extension.LoadString("ButtonTitle"), Extension.LoadString("ButtonHelp") },
    LearnMoreUrl = "https://powerbi.microsoft.com/",
    SourceImage = PQExtension1.Icons,
    SourceTypeImage = PQExtension1.Icons
];

PQExtension1.Icons = [
    Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("PQExtension116.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension120.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension124.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension132.png") },
    Icon32 = { Extension.Contents("PQExtension132.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension140.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension148.png"), Extension.Contents("PQExtension164.png") }
];


StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) =>
        let
            AuthorizeUrl = AuthorizeUrl & Uri.BuildQueryString([
                client_id = client_id,
                client_secret = client_secret,
                response_type="code",
                scope = Scope,
                state = state,
                redirect_uri = redirect_uri])
        in
            [
                LoginUri = AuthorizeUrl,
                CallbackUri = redirect_uri,
                WindowHeight = windowHeight,
                WindowWidth = windowWidth,
                Context = null
            ];

FinishLogin = (context, callbackUri, state) =>
    let
        Parts = Uri.Parts(callbackUri)[Query]
    in
        TokenMethod(Parts[code]);

TokenMethod = (code) =>
    let
        Response = Web.Contents(TokenUri, [
            Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString([
                client_id = client_id,
                client_secret = client_secret,
                grant_type="authorization_code",
                code = code,
                redirect_uri = redirect_uri])),
            Headers=[#"Content-type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",#"Accept" = "application/json"]]),
        Parts = Json.Document(Response)
    in
        Parts;
    '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerBI is probably using IE11 inside the web view controller, and that inherits permissions from your system, which is probably blocking scripts. You can try adding these permissions:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION
DWORD value (32 Bit): Your applciation name.exe = 1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
DWORD value (32 Bit): Your application name.exe = 11001
```

Please also refresh/renew your Forge credential secret, which was exposed above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help,I almost went mad trying to figure out the cause.